# HackerRank Challenge : Find total number of days Plants die

Tags: python, algorithm

> **Problem Statement**
>
> There are N plants in a garden. Each of these plants has been added
>   with some amount of pesticide. After each day, if any plant has more
>   pesticide than the plant at its left, being weaker than the left one,
>   it dies. You are given the initial values of the pesticide in each
>   plant. Print the number of days after which no plant dies, i.e. the
>   time after which there are no plants with more pesticide content than
>   the plant to their left.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The input consists of an integer N. The next line consists of N
>   integers describing the array P where P[i] denotes the amount of
>   pesticide in plant i.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 100000 
>  0 ≤ P[i] ≤ 109
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Output a single value equal to the number of days after which no
>   plants die.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> 7 6 5 8 4 7 10 9
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> 2
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Initially all plants are alive.
>   Plants = {(6,1), (5,2), (8,3), (4,4),
>   (7,5), (10,6), (9,7)}.
>  Plants[k] = (i,j) => jth plant has pesticide
>   amount = i.
>   After the 1st day, 4 plants remain as plants 3, 5, and 6
>   die.
>   Plants = {(6,1), (5,2), (4,4), (9,7)}.
>   After the 2nd day, 3
>   plants survive as plant 7 dies.
>  Plants = {(6,1), (5,2), (4,4)}.
>   After
>   the 3rd day, 3 plants survive and no more plants die.
>   Plants =
>   {(6,1), (5,2), (4,4)}.
>   After the 2nd day the plants stop dying.

**Challenge Link :**  [HackerRank : Poisonous Plant](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/countercode/challenges/poisonous-plants)

**My Submission :** [HackerRank Submission Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/countercode/challenges/poisonous-plants/submissions/code/3542702)

**Failed Test Case 1 :** [Input](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/8763/input15.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1438602531&Signature=QhGv1cjkTHm%2FlUt7VryDgNFiV0o%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) [Output](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/8763/output15.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1438602533&Signature=D%2BwG7kHq6HAvcxmHHy04AxBvrSg%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

**Failed Test Case 2 :** [Input](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/8763/input22.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1438602547&Signature=d91hlPxjscTw0zGxmHYnl%2BAf1EI%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) [Output](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/8763/output22.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1438602550&Signature=Ol8E1LWOTaTSmYA4yr1vGfHAZbg%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

**My Code so Far :**

```
total = int(raw_input())
plants = map(int,raw_input().split())
num_deaths = 1
day = 0
while num_deaths > 0:
    num_deaths = 0
    temp_plants = []
    day += 1
    for i in range(1, len(plants)):
        if plants[i] > plants[i - 1]:
            num_deaths += 1
            continue
        else:
            temp_plants.append(plants[i])
    plants = temp_plants
print(day - 1)
```

It still fails a few test cases. Any suggestions/advice ?

Comment: I noticed you used raw_input even though you using print() as a method and range instead of xrange. While it isn't wrong to do so, it would make more sense to be consistent.  If working with python2.7 it's better to use xrange (as it will yield a generator and therefore kinder to your memory) and for the sake of constancy, use print as a statement.

Comment: Do you get the type of error, as in _too wrong to start_, _crashed_, _wrong result_, _resource limit exceeded_? (I think this can be solved in a single pass.)

Comment: @greybeard No I don't get any of those. It simply says wrong answer for a few of the test cases.

Comment: How many days would it take for the sequence 1,2,3,4 to die ? 1 day (2,3,4 die together) or 2 days (a plant doesn't die if it's left neighbor dies, so 2 and 4 die first, then 3) ?

Comment: 1 day because all 2,3 & 4 die together. We assume that the plants don't die immediately & only at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `Temp_plants` array, you initialize it with `[]`. However, Since you are iterating from index 1, The plant from index 0 is always excluded, so you have to initialize with `[plant[0]]`, since the leftmost plant is always included.

Example: 1 5 4 3 2

**Actual Process**

- 1 5 4 3 2
- 1 4 3 2
- 1 3 2
- 1 2
- 1

Answer=4

**Your Code**

- 1 5 4 3 2
- 4 3 2   [Note that the leftmost 1 is excluded]

Answer=1

Here's a working code which produces correct outputs, but is rather slow. It is correct but is O(n^2) which times out some testcases. This is basically the same as your algo.

```
n= input()
plant=map(int,raw_input().split())
count=0

# At each iteration the following loop updates the plant  
# list by removing weak plants and count counts no. of steps
# temp temporarily stores surviving plants

while(True):
    temp=[plant[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(plant)):
        if plant[i]<=plant[i-1]:    
             temp.append(plant[i])

# If temp and plants have same len, then no plant has
# been removed, so, the process ended.
    if(len(temp)==len(plant)):    break

    plant=temp
    count+=1

print count
```

I'm thinking of a faster dynamic approach that should work, but haven't yet made it work.

Comment: Is there any difference between this code and my code ? If so, please point it out and also how is it better than my code ?

Comment: @DarthShadow: what _does_ get into `temp/_plants`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach for O(n) complexity, this is quite similar to the span finding problems:

```
class Stack():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items==[]
    def peek(self):
        return self.items[-1]
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)

if __name__=="__main__":
    arr = [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1]
    l_a = len(arr)
    stack = Stack()
    e_span = [None]*l_a
    for i in range(l_a):
        elem = arr[i]
        x = None
        max_span = 0
        while not stack.isEmpty() and elem<=arr[stack.peek()]:
            x = stack.pop()
            max_span = max(e_span[x], max_span)
        if stack.isEmpty():
            e_span[i]=0
        elif x is None:
            e_span[i]=1
        else:
            span = max_span+1
            e_span[i]=span
        stack.push(i)
    print max(e_span)
```

Answer (score 1):

passed python version, basically modified the code of @DarthSpeedious and add some comments
    # Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

```
raw_input()

arr = map(int, raw_input().strip().split())

stack = []
days = [0 for i in range(len(arr))]
max_span = 0

for i in range(len(arr)):
    x = None
    max_span = 0 # max_span is only meaningful when the current element smaller than the stack top, so it will get reset for each element.
    while stack != [] and arr[stack[-1]] >= arr[i]:
        x = stack.pop()
        max_span = max(max_span, days[x])

    # if it is the first element, days[i] = 0
    if not stack:
        days[i] = 0
    # if it is the element do not trigger any pop, which means it is greater than its own left(since each element will
    # be pushed to the stack anyway), so the days[i] = 1
    elif not x:
        days[i] = 1
    # if it triggered the pop, which means the arr[i] will wait all the poped element die, then it will die the next day, so days[i] should be the current max_span + 1
    else:
        days[i] = max_span + 1
    stack.append(i)

print max(days)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my java O(n) approach :

**This passes all test cases except 5 testcases leading to a score of 57.50**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PoisonousPlants {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] inputs = new int[n];
        int[] answer = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            inputs[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int min = inputs[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            min = Math.min(inputs[i], min);
            if (inputs[i] > inputs[i - 1]) {
                answer[i] = answer[i] + 1;
            } else {
                if (inputs[i] == min) answer[i] = 0;
                else answer[i] = answer[i - 1] + 1;
            }
        }
        int max = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
            max = Math.max(max, answer[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You are using Java
import java.util.*;
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=input.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[n];
        int a[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        int os=0;
        int s=n;
        int day=0;
        int c=1;
        while(os!=s)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<s;j++)
            {
                if(arr[j]<=arr[j-1])
                {
                    arr[c]=arr[j];
                    c++;
                }
            }
            os=s;
            s=c;
            c=1;
            day++;
        }
        System.out.print(day-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct stack{
  int size;
  int top;
  int * s;
};
int c=0;
int fun(struct stack st);
void push(struct stack * st,int x);
int pop(struct stack * st);
int count(struct stack st);
int main(){
    struct stack st;
    scanf("%d",&st.size);
    st.top=-1;
    st.s=(int*)malloc(st.size*sizeof(int));
    int x;
    for(int i=0;i<st.size;i=i+1){
        scanf("%d",&x);
        push(&st,x);
    }
    int d=fun(st);
    printf("%d",d);
}
int fun(struct stack st){
    int d=0;
    for(int i=st.top;i!=-1;i=i-1){
        //checking if stack elements are in increasing order from top to bottom
        if(i==0){
            d=d+1;
        }
        else if(st.s[i]<st.s[i-1]){
            //simple logic if top element is smallar than top-1 increment d
            d=d+1;
        }
    }
    if(d==count(st)){
        //if the increment d is equal to number of elements in stack then we say they are in increasing order from top to bottom so returning the count i.e number of  times recurrsion as runne
        return c;
    }
    struct stack new_stack;
    new_stack.size=st.size;
    new_stack.top=-1;
    new_stack.s=(int *)malloc(new_stack.size*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=st.top;i!=-1;i=i-1){
        if(i==0){
            push(&new_stack,st.s[st.top]);
        }
       else if(st.s[i]<st.s[i-1]){
           //top is smaller than top-1 then push into stack
            int x=pop(&st);
            push(&new_stack,x);
        }
        else{
            //else do nothing just move ahead
            st.top=st.top-1;
        }
    }
    //now new_stack is created such that elements are in reverse order so we need to reverse the stack elements and put them in new stack
    struct stack rev_st;
    rev_st.size=st.size;
    rev_st.top=-1;
    rev_st.s=(int *)malloc(rev_st.size*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=new_stack.top;i!=-1;i=i-1){
        if(i==0){
            push(&rev_st,new_stack.s[new_stack.top]);
        }
        else{
            int x=pop(&new_stack);
            push(&rev_st,x);
        }
    }
    //now we did one time so increment
    c=c+1;
    //again we do same procedure with this rev_stack until we get increasing order from top to bottom
    fun(rev_st);
}
void push(struct stack * st,int x){
    st->top=st->top+1;
    st->s[st->top]=x;
}
int pop(struct stack * st){
    int temp=st->s[st->top];
    st->top=st->top-1;
    return temp;
}
int count(struct stack st){
    int c=0;
    for(int i=st.top;i!=-1;i=i-1){
        c=c+1;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I would go with an approach where we recursively look at all the elements to the right of the minimum element.

The base case would be if the elements to the right of the min element were sorted!

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

class StackNode {
    int index;
    int element;

    StackNode(int index, int element) {
        this.index = index;
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StackNode [index=" + index + ", element=" + element + "]";
    }
}

public class Solution {

    // Complete the poisonousPlants function below.
    static int poisonousPlants(int[] p) {
        int days = 0;
        List<StackNode> list = new LinkedList<>();
        Stack<StackNode> st = new Stack<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            list.add(new StackNode(i, p[i]));
        }

        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (list.get(i + 1).element > list.get(i).element) {
                    st.push(list.get(i + 1));
                }
            }
            if (st.isEmpty())
                break;
            else {
                days++;
                while (!st.isEmpty()) {
                    list.remove(st.pop());
                }
            }
}
        return days;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not just post code, but instead maybe try to elaborate a bit what you have changed and why you think your example should be considered the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
**I Solve this problem using java**

import java.util.Stack;

public class poison_plants {

    static Stack<Integer>st1= new Stack<>();
    static Stack<Integer>st2= new Stack<>();
    static int count=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    st1.push(6);
    st1.push(5);
    st1.push(8);
    st1.push(4);
    st1.push(7);
    st1.push(10);
    st1.push(9);
    
    
        
    System.out.println(plants());
    }
    private static int plants() {
         
        int checkValue=1;
        int currentvalue,preValue;
        int plantDies=0;
        
        
        while(checkValue!=0) {
        
    
            currentvalue=st1.pop();
            if(st1.size()==1) {
                break;
            }
            preValue=st1.pop();
            
            if(currentvalue<preValue) {
                st1.push(preValue);
                plantDies=1;
                st2.push(currentvalue);

            }else {
                st2.push(currentvalue);
                st1.push(preValue);
            }
        }
        
        if(plantDies!=0) {
            while(!st2.isEmpty()) {
                st1.push(st2.pop());
            }
            checkValue++;
            plants();
        }
    
        return checkValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Here's an easy solution to it!! It passed 26 testcases out of 30.**

```
// Complete the poisonousPlants function below.
  long int poisonousPlants(vector<long int> p) {
  long int j,i,n,c=0,changes=0,m=p.size(),minn;

  for(i=1;i<m;i++)
  {
   if(p[i]>p[i-1])
   {
    changes=1;
    j=i+1;
    minn=p[i];
    while(j<m  && p[j]>p[i-1])
    {
        if(p[j]>p[j-1] && p[j]>minn)
        {
            ++j;
        }
        else if(p[j]>minn)
        {
            minn=min(p[j],minn);  
            ++j; 
        }
        else
        {
            minn=min(p[j],minn);
            ++changes;
            ++j;
        }
    }
    c=max(c,changes);
    }
  }
 return c;
 }
```

## C++

## Hackerrank

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add an answer that passes all the case.

Answer (score -2):

```
static boolean isDescending(int[] p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length - 1; i++) {
        if (p[i] < p[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


static int poisonousPlants(int[] p) {
    if (p == null || p.length == 1 || Arrays.stream(p).distinct().count() == 1 || isDescending(p)) {
        return 0;
    }
    int maxDaysAlive = 0;
    Stack<List<Integer>> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        int item = p[i];
        int daysAlive = 0;
        while (!stack.isEmpty() && item <= stack.peek().get(0)) {
            daysAlive = Math.max(daysAlive, stack.pop().get(1));
        }
        daysAlive = stack.isEmpty() ? 0 :  daysAlive + 1;
        maxDaysAlive = Math.max(maxDaysAlive, daysAlive);
        stack.push(Arrays.asList(item, daysAlive));
    }

    return maxDaysAlive;
}
```

Comment: "Python" requested based on OP. Not sure what you try to achieve here with this non-pythonic answer.